# Finding a winning combination in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let me explain you in more detailed way. I'm trying to make two players Tic Tac Toe game. I have an array of winning combinations. Like that.

```
var winningCombinations = [
  [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9],
  [1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9],
  [1, 5, 9],[3, 5, 7]
];
```

I also have two empty arrays which are populated when one of the players places a blue square or a red square on the board. You can see it in the picture. How to find an identical array or an array with similar numbers (in an array) in the winningCombinations array, so that to determine a winner.

[image: Tic Tac Toe pic.]

```
var player = true;
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
    var listRed = [];
    var listBlue = [];
    var winningCombinations = [
      [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9],
      [1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9],
      [1, 5, 9],[3, 5, 7]
    ];
    squares.forEach(
      function(square) {
        square.addEventListener("click", function() {
          //console.log("clicked");
          if (player) {
            this.classList.add("blue");
            listBlue.push(Number(this.dataset.idx));
            //console.log(typeof Number(this.dataset.idx));
            console.log(`listBlue ${listBlue}`);
            player = false;
          } else {
            this.classList.add("red");
            listRed.push(Number(this.dataset.idx));
            console.log(`listRed ${listRed}`);
            player=true;
          }
        })
      });
```

Comment: Homework problems are welcome, but do show original work toward a solution. The code you posted is just the UI. Where you are stuck with the code to find an identical or similar array?

Comment: If you have some ideas toward solving this problem  please share with me. Maybe some hints. It will be appreciated! I do not expect you to solve this problem for me.

Comment: Hint: Write a function to compare two arrays for equality... come back when you've made progress and are stuck. Here's a [few tips on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce) that I encourage you to read.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy! Of course, I will! By the way, it is by no means a homework project. It is my personal project to practice Js.

Comment: Awesome! Keep at it :)

Comment: You could write a *contains* function to see if a player's list contains the 3 elements of a winning combination.